# Having trouble using where.not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use where.not to replace the following:

```
if @friend_matches.count > 0
  @court_matches = Match.available_on_courts.where('matches.id NOT IN (?)', @friend_matches.pluck(:id)).to_a
else
  @court_matches = Match.available_on_courts
end
```

With

```
    @court_matches = Match.available_on_courts.where.not(matches.id: @friend_matches.pluck(:id)).to_a
```

However I am getting the following errors.

```
SyntaxError: /Users/sripaladugu/Coding/matchpoint_rails/app/mailers/match_mailer.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':'
...on_courts.where.not(matches.id: @friend_matches.pluck(:id))....
...                               ^
/Users/sripaladugu/Coding/matchpoint_rails/app/mailers/match_mailer.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...id: @friend_matches.pluck(:id)).to_a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a hash within `where` to specify table names as keys and column names within the second level:

```
@court_matches = Match.available_on_courts
                      .where.not(matches: { id: @friend_matches.pluck(:id) })
                      .to_a
```